# How can I prevent filters from falling from my earplugs when I remove them?

Tags: maintenance, equipment, hearing

I have a few pairs of flat-response attenuators (a.k.a. musicians earplugs). On one of them, the filters tend to fall when I remove the earplugs from my ear. How can I prevent that?

Demonstration:

Comment: Either the earplugs are bad or somehow you're putting the filters in wrong, it seems to me.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The earplugs work well in terms of attenuation. I have added a video in the question.

Comment: Video is unclear. I'd put a spit of superglue on them. Make sure it's dry before putting back in ear...

Comment: @Tim I still need to be able to change the filters so I don't think superglue is an option. What else do you need to see on the video?

Comment: If they're not too expensive, it's an option, but with a tiny bit of superglue, it should hold them together, and then they can soak in very hot water, and maybe be separated. Possibly a kinder sort of adhesive would do.

Comment: That seems like the constant changing of filters has worn out the rubber piece. You mentioned that you have "a few" pairs, why not just have one pair per each filter that you need set permanently so you don't need to change filters all the time